# Express and calling response.json in a point free fashion doesn't work in Promise.then

Tags: javascript, express, pointfree

Something greatly surprised me today.  I came across a bunch of express route handlers basically look like this (there are more and real function calls, but for the sake of legibility:

```
app.get('/api/foo', (req, resp) => {
  Promise.resolve({one: 1})
    .then(data=>resp.json(data))
})
```

So I, as the clever javascript programmer, think I can step away from the anonymous function and just let the then function call resp.json directly:

```
app.get('/api/foo', (req, resp) => {
  Promise.resolve({one: 1})
    .then(resp.json)
})
```

But when I try that I never get a response and see this in the node console:

> Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'app' of undefined

To my eyes ***.then(resp.json)*** and ***.then(data=>resp.json(data))*** should be equivalent. It's a scope thing, to be sure, but I'd love an explanation and perhaps a workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `resp` is an object with it's own properties, so more than likely the data that is used by the `json` function is contained within the `resp` object.

When you pass the function `resp.json` by itself to `then`, you aren't passing the `resp` object, or any of its information, along with it. **In essence, the `then` call is just "borrowing" the function `json` from the `resp` object**. Just the function body itself though, no scope or implicit values.

More than likely, the function body of `json` uses `this` somewhere, at which point you will be getting an invalid (probably global) object, instead of `resp`.

To remedy, you can do

```
   Promise.resolve({one: 1})
    .then(resp.json.bind(resp))
```

Comment: Ha. You are correct. I just figured it out.  Thanks! But its' ugly that way, might as well use the fat arrow function.

Answer (score 3):

They are not the same because of how [the `this` operator works in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Basically, `resp.json(data)` calls the function with `this===resp`, while `resp.json` calls the function with `this===global`.

To fix it, pass the function with bound parameters `.then(resp.json.bind(resp))` (or use the arrow function).